# Special character not replacing in react issue

Tags: html, reactjs

I have one field in my database called description-long which has long description in html format and i am retrieving content using following code.

```
 this.props.product.descriptionLong.split("<br />").map((description, index) => <p key={index}>{description} <br/></p>)
```

but some reason special character is not converted and it is rendered as it is:

```
        De tijdelijke nep tatoeages in het maximale formaat 50 x 50 mm, u bent
     vrij in het formaat zolang het er maar binnen past! In elke vorm, maat en kleur te drukken. Uiteraard full-color bedrukt. Makkelijk op de 
huid aan te brengen door ze te bevochtigen met water, even aandrukken en 
de papieren drager te verwijderen. Tijdelijke tattoo&#039;s die 5-7 dagen 
blijven zitten, misschien wel langer! Verwijder de neptattoo&#039;s 
eventueel al eerder met een beetje (baby) olie!<br />
        <br /> Per stuk verpakt in een polybag of als bulk geleverd. <br />
        <br />
```

*using above code i am getting output like this*

De tijdelijke nep tatoeages in het maximale formaat 50 x 50 mm, u bent vrij in het formaat zolang het er maar binnen past! In elke vorm, maat en kleur te drukken. Uiteraard full-color bedrukt. Makkelijk op de huid aan te brengen door ze te bevochtigen met water, even aandrukken en de papieren drager te verwijderen. Tijdelijke tattoo& #039;s die 5-7 dagen blijven zitten, misschien wel langer! Verwijder de neptattoo& #039;s eventueel al eerder met een beetje (baby) olie!

Naast de normale full-color opdruk kunnen ook speciale effecten toegepast worden zoals glow-in-the-dark inkt, metallic inkt en glitters. De neptatoeages worden helemaal op maat gemaakt, dus ook de (verplichte) gebruiksaanwijzing op de achterzijde kan aangepast worden. Per stuk verpakt in een polybag of als bulk geleverd.

*Is there any way to get the (& #039;) special character from code ?*
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code as:

```
this.props.product.descriptionLong.split("<br />").map((description, index) => {
  const htmlText = {
    __html: description
  };
  return <p key={index} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlText} />;
});
```

Read [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) documentation.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/y24n4w15v9)